# Proof by induction that $5|11^n-6$ for all positive integers $n$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

> Prove by induction that $5|11^n-6$ for all positive integers $n$

Let $p(n) = 11^n-6.$ We have $p(1) = 5$, thus it holds for $p(1)$. Assume it holds for $p(k)$. We will prove that it's true for $p(k+1)$. We have $p(k+1) = 11^{k+1}-6$. But $6 = 11^k-f(k).$ Thus

$$f(k+1) = 11\cdot 11^k-11^k+f(k) = 10\cdot 11^k+f(k). $$

$5|(10\cdot 11^k+f(k))$ by hypothesis thus the statement is true for $p(k+1)$. Hence it's true for $p(n)$.

Is the above correct?

Comment: Does $P(2)$ hold?

Comment: Do you mean $5 | 11^n - 6$ instead?

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes. Edited it. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are small corrections to your post. Define $a_{n}=11^{n}-6$. Let $P(n)$ be a predicate defined by $$P(n):5\mid a_{n}.$$ You have shown that $P(1)$ is true. Assume that $P(k)$ is true for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Then $a_{k}=5m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. Notice that $$a_{k+1}=11^{k+1}-6=5(11m+12).$$ This shows that $a_{k+1}$ is a multiple of $5$, so $5\mid a_{k+1}$. You can conclude the rest on your own.

Comment: Thanks! Is what's wrong in original post that $5|(10\cdot 11^k+f(k))$ is not justified? My thinking was that $5|f(k)$ by the hypothesis and clearly $5|10 \cdot 11^k$ so therefore it divides their sum.

Comment: @user276387 If you say that $p(1)$ is true as a statement, then you can not define $p(n)=11^{n}-6$ where the  equality sign is added since $p(n)$ is a predicate. Your $f(k)$ is same as mine $a_{k}$. By the way, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=11^n-6$ then $$11^{n+1}-6=11(x+6)-6=11x+60$$ and this later is divisible by $5$ if $x$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $5\mid 11^n-6\implies 11^n-6=5k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
\begin{align*}
11(11^n-6)&=11\cdot5k \\
11^{n+1}-11\cdot 6+60&=11\cdot 5k+60 \\
11^{n+1}-6&=11\cdot 5k+60 \\
11^{n+1}-6&=5(11k+12)
\end{align*}

$$11^{n+1}-6=5(11k+12)\implies 5\mid 11^{n+1}-6$$

So we have shown
$$5\mid 11^n-6\implies 5\mid 11^{n+1}-6$$

Check $5\mid 11^1-6$, and conclude $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},5\mid 11^n-6$.